# Empty “open recent” menu in Xcode 4.6.3

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, osx-mountain-lion, xcode

So there's nothing in "open recent" and it always have been this way.

I tried to "defaults write com.apple.Xcode NSRecentDocumentsLimit -int 10" (and with the other name).

In settings->general there is "show 10 recent items".

That's all I could find and nothing has worked so far.

Comment: You could try deleting ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.LSSharedFileList.plist.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. In recents i can only see recent project files. In open files in the left menu "recent files" are only those files that are open in that window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180100/xcode-doesnt-show-recent-projects-in-recent-projects-list